# What is Interface name in QueuePause

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

Anyone can tell me what is interface name for QueuePause action (Asterisk Manager Interface).
http://astbook.asteriskdocs.org/en/2nd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/asterisk-APP-F-30.html

I try "SIP/2222" (connected extesion) but it alway throws "Interface Not found".
I don't khow how to get right interface, does one please tell me how to make this action work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem, 
it was because the agent (or in your case sip) wasn't assigned to any queues

Answer (score 2):

Verify the interfaces on queue with "queue show":

```
trantor*CLI> queue show teste
teste        has 0 calls (max unlimited) in 'ringall' strategy (0s holdtime), W:0, C:0, A:0, SL:0.0% within 0s
   Members:
       SIP/1000 (realtime) (Unavailable) has taken no calls yet
   No Callers
```

So i can send a QueuePause event using interface SIP/1000. It will only pause interfaces that belong to at least one Queue.